# PHP preg_match on text not working

Tags: php

This php code is not catching numeric characters or symbols as it should.

```
$firstname = check_input($_POST['firstname'], "Please enter your first name");
$firstname = ucwords($firstname);
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
  show_error("Name should have only alpha characters and white space");
}
```

For example, the results should be Geronimo. If ge5on*mo is entered, that's what gets returned.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your test-cases with `real` and `expected` outcome ?

Comment: Your regular expression looks fine. What is the problem exactly? What is the value of `$firstname`?

Comment: We need more info. "as it should" means nothing if you don't know what it *should* do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no full test cases in your example. So I will try to walk blindly in the dark. At first your expression is flawed, because it can capture just empty spaces without any name. Second - it doesn't captures unicode characters. I would start with such expression for name capture :
[`^(?:\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+[-\h]?){1,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/cnV0mQ/2)

Explanation:

`^(?:
\p{Lu}    // first letter in name must be in upper-case
\p{Ll}+   // after that goes at least 1 non-upper case letter
[-\h]?    // we allow separators between names
){1,}     // human can have multiple names (at least 1)
$`